# Script to buffer 2 shapefiles within each folder of root folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I need some help with ArcGIS python script

My folder tree is like this:

/Testing location

```
C1

    POIS.shp
    STREETS.shp
C2
```

etc, etc

I'm trying to make a script to run from arcgis that would go into each folder from the main directory and buffer the two shapefiles, output a specific file (Surrounding_Streets.shp for example) for each layer in each respective folder.

So within each folder I'd now have POIS.shp, POIS_SURROUNDING.shp, STREETS.shp, and STREETS_SURROUNDING.shp

Answer (score 2):

See the ArcGIS Desktop help topic on [Listing data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Listing_data/002z00000011000000/) for how to access feature classes (shapefiles) inside workspaces (subfolders).

Generally, you will need to set the main env.workspace, loop through `folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*', 'Folder')`, reset the env.workspace to the 'folders' list item, and use another loop `fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(wildcard)`, where 'wildcard' corresponds to your specific shapefiles (which can also be a list that is looped through). Tends to be slow...

If you would like to use a faster python module for listing the subfolders try [**os.listdir**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). And a somewhat similar post to yours can be seen [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/arcgis-10-python-script-to-search-directories-and-subdirectories-for-intersects?rq=1) using [**os.walk**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk).

My favorite is [**glob**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) with the relevant wildcard (e.g. '*.shp') - a subfolder/sudirectory example is shown in this [PyMOTW - glob](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/glob/). Below is code specific to your shapefiles:

```
import arcpy
import glob
main_dir = r'C:\Testing\location'
# Loop through all files by wildcard
for wildcard in ['POIS.shp', 'STREETS.shp']:
    # Specify the subdirectory variable and specific shapefile name to match
    sub_dir = main_dir + '/*/' + wildcard
    # Loop through files in subdirectory
    for in_fc in glob.glob(sub_dir):
        # Specify output variable
        out_fc = in_fc.rstrip('.shp') + '_Surrounding.shp'
        # Buffer - insert your own parameters here
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_fc, out_fc, "100 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL")
```

You could use an attribute field for the distance value or specify this using a dictionary  (instead of the wildcard list in the example) in case you need different buffer distances for each shapefile type.

Comment: I agree with @ccn except that rather than use os.walk or glob, if you are using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 (or later) then using [**arcpy.da.Walk**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) instead would mean only having to import arcpy.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for late reply, but I got the job done using os.listdir.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of using the `glob` module for this sort of work as @ccn has shown, however, `arcpy.da.Walk()` was designed for this sort of task.  For example:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r"C:\temp"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        print dirpath
        print filename
        infc = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        outfc = os.path.join(dirpath, filename.split(".")[0] + "_SURROUNDINGS")
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis (infc, outfc, 10) # Buffer by 10m for example
```