# Merge Shapefiles using a loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, merge

I'm a new user of ArcMap. And I'm not good at programming language.

There are the following shapefiles in workspace.

```
L01-1983_01.shp
L01-1983_02.shp
...
L01-1983_46.shp
L01-1983_47.shp
L01-1984_01.shp
L01-1984_02.shp
...
L01-1984_46.shp
L01-1984_47.shp
...
L01-2012_01.shp
L01-2012_02.shp
...
L01-2012_46.shp
L01-2012_47.shp
L01-2013_01.shp
L01-2013_02.shp
...
L01-2013_46.shp
L01-2013_47.shp
```

File name has the following rule.

```
L01-(year)_(city code).shp
```

I want to merge all shapefiles for each year, for example,

```
L01-1983_01.shp
L01-1983_02.shp
...
L01-1983_46.shp
L01-1983_47.shp
-----merge----    L01_1983.shp
...
L01-2013_01.shp
L01-2013_02.shp
...
L01-2013_46.shp
L01-2013_47.shp
-----merge----    L01_2013.shp
```

Below is my script.

```
list_year=["list_%d" % x for x in range(1983,2014)]
year=1983
for i in list_year:
    i=ListFeatureClasses("*year*")
    year=year+1
years=range(1983,2014)
for i in years:
    Merge_management(list_i,"L01_i.shp")
```

But I can't get merged files.

How can I write python script to merge shapefiles using a loop?

Comment: [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54491/how-to-merge-many-shapefiles-in-different-folders?rq=1) should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work for you.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

in_folder = r"C:\GIS\Temp"
arcpy.env.workspace = in_folder

years = list(range(1983,2014))

for year in years:
    shp_paths = []
    list_shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*{0}*".format(year))
    if list_shps:
        for shp in list_shps:
            desc = arcpy.Describe(shp)
            shppath = desc.catalogPath
            shp_paths.append(shppath)
        print shp_paths
        arcpy.Merge_management(shp_paths,"L01_{0}".format(year))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, as your script, I can't get merged files.

Comment: You have not copied the code as it is (at least it doesn't look right in the question body). Refer to the Esri Help pages to read more about Python scripting if you need adjust your code further to meet your needs.